# Can Arcane Trickster/Wizard use their Arcane Trickster's Spell Slots to cast Wizards spells that are not Enchantments or Illusions?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, spellcasting, spell-slots

Can multiclass Arcane Trickster/Wizard use their Arcane Trickster's Spell Slots to cast Wizards spells they know that are not Enchantments or Illusions?

Comment: I kindly suggest to divide what you are asking in two different questions.

Comment: I've closed this as dupe, as I believe it has been asked before. Let us know if the linked question is insufficient for solving your problem and we will see what we can do too get this question clarified and reopened.

Comment: In case it was a bit unclear; the linked question establishes that spell slots are shared when multiclassing (except with Warlock). Thus "Arcane Trickster Spell Slots" do not exist at all. Does this answer your question?